# A $(n \times n)$ matrix is orthogonal if and only if its rows form an orthonormal basis of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The key point in the first direction of this proof I was reading wrote that:

By the definition of matrix multiplication, $AA^T = I_n$ implies $\mathbf{r_i} \cdot \mathbf{r_i} = 1$ and $\mathbf{r_i} \cdot \mathbf{r_j} = 0$ for $i \neq j$.

But how, I don't 'see' how this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a very simple example.  If $A= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ then $A^T= \begin{bmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}$ and $AA^T=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & c \\ b & d\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a^2+ b^2 & ac+ bd \\ ac+ bd & c^2+ d^2\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

So we must have $a^2+ b^2$ and $c^2+ d^2$, the lengths of the two "row vectors" equal to 1, and $ac+ bd$, the dot product of the two "row vectors", equal to 0.

Comment: Very helpful too :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of matrix multiplication to check that the entry at the index $(i,j)$ of $AA^T$ is $\mathbf{r_i} \cdot \mathbf{r_j}$. This is pretty much all one can say about that.

Comment: I have tried to write out the definition of matrix multiplication, but I don't really know how to manipulate the sums/limits/indices. Could you show me please?

Comment: You do not have to manipulate anything. It is immediate.

Comment: The $i$th row of $A$ consists of $a_{i,1},a_{i,2},\ldots,a_{i,n}$. The $j$th column of $A^T$ (or the $j$th row of $A$) consists of $a_{j,1},a_{j,2},\ldots,a_{j,n}$. So by the rules of matrix multiplication you obtain $a_{i,1}a_{j,1}+\ldots+a_{i,n}a_{j,n}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you, writing it like that really helps :) I understand the proof now